# How to uninstall this tricky P trap?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, cleaning, pvc

I have trouble replacing this kind of P trap as shown in the Figure below.

Different from a normal P trap (e.g., here https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7MWn.jpg ), threre is no such "wrench stuff".

I marked the joints in the figure with red color. The joints can be rotated, but I just can't remove it. Or do I just need more muscle power to remove it by force?

So how to uninstall this P trap?

[image]

Comment: See if the collars slip up or down and then try pulling the pipes apart.  If not, try brute force.

Comment: @JACK Thanks, but that's my point. The collar won't slip down...

Comment: Just curious, where in the world are you? I've never seen plumbing with sharp angles like that... Water usually flows much better through smooth curves, especially if there's food waste involved (that seems to be a kitchen drain with dishwasher).

Comment: @FreeMan In Finland. To be honest, this is the most weird plumbing I've ever seen

Comment: I'd seriously consider removing it with a hacksaw and replacing it with a normal trap (like in your linked image), but, before you take that leap, wait to see if anyone has any better suggestions for you. There may be reasons for that in Finland that I'm not aware of.

Comment: It is a weird looking contraption. Maybe it's not meant to come apart.

Comment: I thought locking collar also Japan had some weird (to me) plumbing like this but I did not have to work on it I noticed it because it was different. I would take a photo to your local plumbing store and ask them if there is a trick , brute force or replacement. They will know the common methods it may be a 1 time press on with an oring seal , metal tabs bite into the pipe so it won’t come off kind of like a shark bite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicate that the fittings will spin, but not unscrew. That indicates to me that they are some sort of a "snap" fitting that goes on, but either has to have a special tool to remove or has to be cut off.

You say you're *REPLACING* the trap. In that case, using a hacksaw* to cut it out is probably the simplest and most expedient method of removal.

***HOWEVER*** - If you cut the drain tail-piece (the one you're holding on to), it's quite likely that you will not have enough pipe left to attach a new, standard screw-on trap to. To that end, I'd suggest that you also purchase a new tail piece for your sink with the expectation that you'll have to replace it. Keep your receipt and return it if you end up not needing to replace it.

An alternative would be to hacksaw through the fitting along the length of the pipe to cut it open and allow you to spread it so you can remove the trap. You might need to make 2 cuts, to cut the fitting in half so you can simply lift each part of the fitting off. This will preserve the full length of the drain tail-piece, but will probably be a more difficult cut to make. You may be able to make the 2 cuts roughly 1/4 - 1/3 the pipe circumference from each other and stretch the fitting the rest of the way to get it off if you can't get to the back side to make them 1/2 circumference apart. Of course, if the fitting is rotating freely, make one cut, spin it 1/2 way around, then make the other cut.

**I keep seeing "HACK" on the pipe, just above your thumb and keep thinking that's a hint. :D*

Comment: Indeed, hacking is the final solution to all problem.